What determines roleAndSubordinatesInternal Type for a Group?
Some context:
When uploading sharing rules to a sandbox org I experienced and error "sharedFrom not allowed:roleAndSubordinates - {name}"
Never had this issue earlier so I investigated and I found that when Roles are created (which is a Group with role as type) Salesforce automatically creates so called sharing Groups with roleAndSubordinate as type. Makes sense. (Role and Territory Sharing Groups)
Turned out I got the error because the referenced Group was not a roleAndSubordinate type, but roleAndSubordinateInternal type. I adjusted the tags in the metadata and now it works.
The issue:
When we upload the roles, we don't have an opportunity to specify which type Groups should be created. We uploaded them the same way as always. What controls whether the type of these Groups Internal or not? What could've been changed in the org, so that some of the roles genereted these new type Groups?
So far we used only the roleAndSubordinates tag in the sharing rule metadata, and we need to know why and in which cases we have to change it to roleAndSubordinatesInternal.
(In our org, we upload roles and user data from an external system, keeping these updated all the time.)
I thank you for any relevant insights!

Turned out it's due to the Winter ’25 release. The roleAndSubordinates will be replaced by roleAndSubordinatesInternal and in the preview-sandboxes it was released earlier then in others. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=002628970&type=1
